# How to rewrite all authentication/registration related URL's in a Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any way to rewrite all URL's that are related to the authentication and registration (including things like 'lost password') for a Wordpress-based website? This means not just concocting some .htaccess-based rewrite rules, but also having the links change throughout these pages.

Comment: Give us an example of what you want; otherwise the question is too vague.